# How to convert a non SDK style project to an SDK style project programmatically?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I know how to manipulate a non SDK style project file programmatically:

1. Create `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` instance.
2. Make the changes through its API, e.g. add/remove `Items` or `Properties`
3. Call `Save` function

Now I would like to write code that converts a non SDK style project to an SDK style project when the following is given:

- All the nuget references are already through `PackageReference`
- The project is friendly to conversion, i.e. it references all the source files in the project directory and has no special targets or properties or imports or items.

The manual conversion is straightforward, but I want to automate it. What I do not understand is what kind of `Project` object manipulation should I do so that when it is saved the root `Project` element no longer has the xml namespace and instead has the `Sdk` attribute? All the rest, like stripping it of all the fluff I think I can do.

**EDIT 1**

Actually, I am also interested to know if there is a way to know whether the given reference is part of the SDK and hence does not need to be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert should give you a starting point.

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks.